# R smoothScatter error: Binning grid too coarse for current

Tags: r, plot

I need to create a plot of 2 dense datasets in R. According to the documentation, the `smoothScatter()` function is better suited at these situations than the `plot()` function. However, when I run the `smoothScatter()` I encounter the following error.

`Binning grid too coarse for current (small) bandwidth: consider increasing 'gridsize'`

Here's the piece of code:

```
myScatterPlot <- function(x,y,data,string){
    c <- paste0(data, string, collapse=NULL);
    c <- paste0(c, ".jpg", collapse=NULL);
    jpeg(c, quality=100);
    smoothScatter(x,y,nrpoints=100,main=string);
    dev.off();
}
```

**Questions**

**1)** What is the source of this error?

**2)** Is there an easier way of achieving this result?

Comment: You should focus on the first sentence of your question rather than the remainder. This is [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: @shayaa. I reworded the question to make it broader and try to solve the aforementioned problem. I also found a workaround passing a higher than standard **nbin** argument to the `smoothScatter()` function.